# VBA macro routine for copying and pasting large amounts of data between worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for a VBA routine that will allow the same copy and paste procedure to happen repeatedly while moving through a long worksheet of data.  I'm interested in copying a small area of cells that repeat through out a worksheet and are the same distance away from the next selection area I need.

```
Sheets("Excel_Essex_Helos_Dump_80520_12").Select
Range("B6").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Excel_Essex_Helos_Dump_80520_12").Select
Range("D6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Excel_Essex_Helos_Dump_80520_12").Select
Range("F6").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B6").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Excel_Essex_Helos_Dump_80520_12").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=24
Range("A47:A73").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

So basically on the next go around I want to select "B79" and then "D79" and "F79" etc.  Each next cell will be 73 cells away from the previous one.  Is there a routine I can create that adds 73 to the range and repeats until finished?

Comment: `For i = 1 to 50,000 Step 73` Read about For Loops.

Comment: Although it isn't pertaining to your immediate question, take a look at [this SO question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) about how to avoid select statements. It will help your code immensely.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but you can easily **Copy >> Paste** without using `Select` and `ActiveSheet` all the time.

If you want to copy (and include formatting and/or formulas) use :

```
With Sheets("Excel_Essex_Helos_Dump_80520_12")
    .Range("B6").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4")
End With
```

If you want to copy only the values you can use :

```
With Sheets("Excel_Essex_Helos_Dump_80520_12")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value = .Range("B6").Value
End With
```

Now, you can incorporate the Row Number and Column Number for the source and destination worksheets.

Comment: Thanks Shai, this is definitely helpful.  Any idea on how to get this routine to repeat throughout a really long worksheet.  I think the cells go all the way down to 50,000....